# Find the first three nonzero terms in the Laurent series expansion of $f$ in a region

Tags: complex-analysis, taylor-expansion, laurent-series

$f(z) = 1/(1-cosz)$

Region is $0 < |z| < 2pi$

---

**My work:**

$f(z) = 1/(1-cos(z-2pi))$

$1-cos(z-2pi) = (z-2pi)^2/2! - (z-2pi)^4/4! + (z-2pi)^6/6! - ....$ (*)

--> $1/$(*) $= 2/(z-2pi)^2 + 1/6 + (z-2pi)^2/120 + ...$

---

I don't know what the answer is, but I doubt it's this. Any idea on how to go about doing it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

\begin{align}
f(z)
&= \dfrac{1}{1-\cos z} \\
&= \dfrac{1}{\frac{1}{2!}z^2-\frac{1}{4!}z^4+\frac{1}{6!}z^6+\cdots} \\
&= \frac{2}{z^2}\left(\dfrac{1}{1-\frac{1}{12}z^2+\frac{1}{360}z^4+\cdots}\right) \\
&= \frac{2}{z^2}\left(1+\frac{1}{12}z^2+\frac{1}{240}z^4+\cdots\right) \\
&= \frac{2}{z^2}+\dfrac{1}{6}+\frac{1}{120}z^2+\cdots
\end{align}

Comment: how are you accounting for the region when finding this? Also, if you don't mind me asking, what would one do if, say, the region was pi < z < 2pi or 0 < z < pi?

Comment: the function $\cos z$ is analytic in $|z|<2\pi$ and with the pole $z=0$ of order $2$ for function $\dfrac{1}{1-\cos z}$, it's Laurent series is valid in $0<|z|<2\pi$.

Comment: If the region were to change as mentioned above, how would the answer differ? Thanks for the help, by the way

Comment: This series is valid in $0<|z|<2\pi$, and $\pi<|z|<2\pi$ is subset of $0<|z|<2\pi$, in addition to it's valid for every subset of $0<|z|<2\pi$.